# Is there a way to deploy a VSTS project in an app service using an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm creating resources on Azure using an ARM template. I have three web apps to deploy. Normally i can deploy them separately using VSTS which is slow. So is there a way to deploy a project on VSTS using an ARM template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy a template that uses web deploy to also deploy a web app - you can deploy to slots or deploy to an existing web app (not defined in your ARM template).  This sample has an MSDeploy extension that does the work.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-blob-connection

You can also go this route:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/

Both can be done via VSTS...

Comment: I'm having a look at this now. I've deployed one app, but i'm going to try to deploy multiple apps using this method.

Comment: Indeed this does work. Just need to change the web apps .csprog file to allow an OutputPath.

Comment: oh and if the project does not have an OutputPath setup. The deployment will fail without error.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to export ARM template from your azure RM portal.

Make sure

1. you have single resource group where all these apps have been deployed (since you want to deploy them together).
2. Export the resource management template and attach to your VSTS project as resource.
3. Add a new release task in your VSTS as Azure Resource Group Deployment.
4. Add connection details to your resource group.
5. Specify the previously exported template
6. Configure the parameters (or use variables).

you should be able to use VSTS build and release management to deploy ARM resources.